# why is it a bad practise to not initialize primitive fields in a class?

Tags: java, initialization, primitive

Java primitives always have a default value in the memory of O (booleans are false = 0). So why is it considered as a bad practise to not initialize them, if they even have a predefined value because of this mechanic? And in arrays, even with initialization of a new int[8], all the values in it arent really initialized, but that isnt frowned upon...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**ALL** instance variables are initialized. If you don't specify a value, the default value is used.

Who says it's bad practice to not initialize instance variables? I tend not to initialize them unless it's to a non-default value, but it's not a big deal either way. It's about readability and reducing "code noise" improves readability. Useless initializing is code noise IMHO.

Comment: Strongly agree. It's a throw-back from other languages where default values are not guaranteed.

Comment: people in IRC were complaining about me not initializing booleans (i used them to state, if i already cached a certain thing,which would then stay true after setting it to true)

Comment: +1. Don't initialize variables if you don't have to!

Comment: No. You should not silently rely on defaults. Why not write it out and make it clear to everyone?

Comment: @CedricReichenbach it is clear: 0 for numeric, false for boolean, null for objects.

Comment: That's not the point. The question is if you need it to be 0 right after declaration or if you don't care (yet). And that's a big difference.

Comment: They are considered bad practice as stated in the Oracle documentation. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html (see Default Values).  Only class fields are initialized to 0, local variables are slightly different; the compiler never assigns a default value to an uninitialized local variable.

Comment: @dstibbe this is obviously a question about instance variables. As we all know, local variables *must* be initialized so there's no choice (or question) in the matter. The documentation (which is archaic and no one cares about) says "bad style" not "bad practice" - there is a big difference between those two terms.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach The implicit defaults already are clear to *everyone*---except those who haven't yet learned Java. The difference between caring and not caring is an artificial one. God help me if I ever rely on that distinction while debugging code...

Comment: @dstibbe That document lost its relevance a long time ago. Among other ridiculosities, it advocates declaring all local variables at the top of the method, as if Java was K&R C.

Comment: Well, those are details that make code slightly more readable. If I read sth like `int x;` and later `int y = x + 2`, I will try to find out where the writer assigns a value to x. If I won't find it, I'll assume they forgot to do so.

Comment: @CedricReichenbach That's either tongue-in-cheek, or you aren't yet seriously enough into Java programming. When you look at an instance field, you *must* have the proper intuition to "see" the default value---otherwise you can't really read Java. There are many similar examples around the language---like "seeing" the implicit enclosing instance of an inner class.

Comment: In the code of a tool that visualizes Java objects I developed, I came across a method which analyzes/visualizes booleans. For distinctions there, I even wrote `if (myBoolean == true) makeItGreen();`, just to emphasize we're "investigating" the object `myBoolean` and it's not a simple condition. I think the whole thing can be compared to driving a car by day with headlights on. It doesn't really bother you, but may clearly help in certain situations, so why not do it?

Comment: @CedricReichenbach I'm a big believer in "less code is good". This applies from higher level perfunctory useless classes, right down to line fragments that can be expressed more succinctly, including useless initialization - it's all code noise and an insidious form of obfuscation, because the essence  of the code is diluted. Minimal code is easier to read and clearer simply because there's less of it.

Comment: @Bohemian I agree that lean, precise code is better. E.g. smart organization of `if`s, loops and `try`-`catch` blocks can reduce both method length and nesting levels, making the code more readable. But explicitly initializing variables (where reasonable) doesn't make code less readable. Omitting those initializations actually reduces the code's expressiveness.

Answer (score 6):

By explicitly defining a value, it's clear that you intended that value at that point of execution. If not, another reader might interpret it as if you either forgot to initialize this variable or you don't care at that point (and will set it somewhere else later).

In other words, it's some kind of implicit documentation. Generally, it's considered better practice to write verbose code for better readability; i.e. never use abbreviations for methods names, write them out!

Also, if you have to write line comments (`//`), you can almost always replace them by wrapping the following code into a well-named method. Implicit documentation ftw! :)

Comment: Yes. I think it might even be optimized away by the compiler, thus no technical difference.

Comment: It can't be "optimized away". The semantics of initial values are designed for easy implementation by zeroing out each newly allocated block on the heap.

Answer (score 1):

Say i am writing a small game and every single entity (enemy, player etc) starts with 100 health, there is no point in using a sethealth(100) method every time a new entity is created.

So basically, imo unless you need to use a certain value other than zero, I would not initialize them. Same goes for booleans, unless you need something to be true right off the bat, no point in touching it.

Answer (score 0):

Its not bad practice, and Ive seen experienced developers who do initialise, and those who dont.

My preference is to initialise as it shows the developer has taken time to consider what the values should be on start up, and is not just relying on the compiler using defaults

Answer (score -1):

It is not bad practice to initialize instance variable of class. But it is bot necessory to initialize it, because if you forgot or not initialize it, default value is assign to it.
Initialization required when we want that class instance variable/s must have some value at the time of initialization of class object.